# ¿Cómo debería hacer para que me de true , cuándo solo hay un dígito de diferencia?

Tags: java

El enunciado del problema es:

> Escribir un método en Java que reciba como argumentos dos valores de
> tipo entero, ambos con igual cantidad de dígitos, convierta cada
> número recibido a su correspondiente representación en binario
> los números en binario difieren solamente en uno de sus dígitos Por ejemplo: con los siguientes números en binario, el método retorna true, porque entre ellos solo difiere un digito.  el método retorna false, porque entre ellos difiere más de un digito.

> No es permitido la utilización de métodos propios de Java, cómo debería hacer para que al Dividir el número entero entre dos y anotar en una columna a la derecha el resto (un 0 si el resultado de la división es par y un 1 si es impar). Esto hasta que la división de como resultado 1.
> ¿Cómo debería hacer para que me de true , cuándo solo hay un dígito de diferencia?

Comment: Así de pronto, podrías calcular un NAND binario entre los dos números. Si el resultado es potencia de 2, entonces solo cambia uno de los dígitos. Si no es potencia de 2 entonces hay más de un dígito que cambia

Answer (score 0):

creo que lo mejor seria recorrer el numero en binario en una función y usando chartAt[i] en un for hasta binario.size(), crear un vector entero de 2 posiciones, y a su ves dos contadores uno para el cero y otro para el uno, haces la comparación con un if-else if o Switch y allí aumentas los contadores para uno y para cero, una vez termine el ciclo estos números  se los asignas al vector en el vector [uno, cero] o vice-versa y sera el valor que vas a retornar, luego creas otra función donde creas la instancia y le pasas los parámetros( el numero binario), y el vector que te retorna de los contadores 1 o 0, los comparas y sabrás la diferencia de cuantos dígitos difieren, espero te pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Los binarios trátalos como String, es más fácil compararlos después y se previene un error de overflow si el entero es muy grande.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Binarios {
    
    public String ConverBin(int numero1) { 
            // TODO: realizar implementación manual de este código
            return Integer.toBinaryString(numero1);
    }

public char[] Separacion(String numero1) {

    char[] nums;

    nums = numero1.toCharArray();
    for (char c : nums) {
        System.out.print(c + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    return nums;
}

public boolean gray(int numero1, int numero2) {

    // cambio el int por un String
    String binario1, binario2;

    binario1 = ConverBin(numero1);
    binario2 = ConverBin(numero2);

    System.out.println("prueba " + binario1 + " y " + binario2);

    char[] Espaciar1;
    char[] Espaciar2;
    
    int cont = 0;

    Espaciar1 = Separacion(binario1);

    Espaciar2 = Separacion(binario2);
    
    
    int diferencia = Math.abs(binario1.length() - binario2.length());
    
    // igualar las cadenas
    // se rellena con cero a la izquierda la cadena más corta
    if(binario1.length() > binario2.length()){
      for(int i = 0; i < diferencia; i++){
          binario2 = "0" + binario2;
      }
    }else{
        
         for(int i = 0; i < diferencia; i++){
          binario1 = "0" + binario1;
      }
        
    }
   
    int contador = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < binario1.length(); i++){
        
        // si los binarios en esta posición son diferentes incrementar contador
        if(binario1.charAt(i) != binario2.charAt(i)) contador++;
        
        // si contador ya es mayor que 1 terminar el ciclo, esto es por optimización
        if(contador > 1) break;
        
    }
  
    
    // retornar la condición
   return contador == 1;
    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Binarios jp = new Binarios();

    int num1, num2;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Digite numero entero: ");
    num1 = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Digite otro numero entero: ");
    num2 = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println(jp.gray(num1, num2));

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que podrias resumirlo a esto:
Ejemplo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Convertimos el decimal ingresado a equivalente gray
        int gray1 = DecimalToGray(3);
        int gray2 = DecimalToGray(4);
        //Diferenciamos el minimo y el maximo para la resta absoluta.
        int max = Math.max(gray1, gray2);
        int min = Math.min(gray1, gray2);
        //Convertimo la diferencia a un string binario
        String strBin = Integer.toString(max - min, 2);
        //Hacemos un split para separar los numeros en la cadena binaria.
        String sep[] = strBin.split("");
        //Ejemplo si da como resultado 10000   
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sep.length; i++) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(sep[i], 10);
        }
        //Si la suma da 1 es true.
        boolean condition = (sum == 1);

        System.out.println(condition);

    }

    public static int DecimalToGray(int decimal) {
        return decimal + (decimal >> 1);
    }
```